# Mysql convert VARCHAR to date using REGEX

Tags: mysql

I have a VARCHAR field in mysql with dates separated by commas. Like this:

```
"10/20/2011,10/21/2011,10/22/2011"
```

I need to use a WHERE condition like this:

```
where `date` > '10/10/2011'
```

So my question is basically how can i use (maybe) regex to retrieve the first date in my field (I only need the first) and apply the where condition to it?

Comment: What technology are you invoking the MySQL from?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing a comma separated list in a single cell. I think you should restructure your database and add a table, since you seem to have a `many to many` relationship here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get only the first part, before the comma `,` :

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX( varcharField, ',' , 1)
```

You then need to convert it into `date` format:

```
STR_TO_DATE( SUBSTRING_INDEX(varcharField, ',', 1), '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have already been told, storing a comma delimited list is a bad idea. But many times it's not within your job duties or abilities to restructure a table.

I think you should look up doing full-text indexes and matching. This will allow for searching within a field. Sadly only available on MyISAM tables.